# Improve SQL performance for populating List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, performance, c#-3.0

I have 200,000 records in a database with the PK as a varchar(50)

Every 5 minutes I do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE`

If that result is greater than the List.Count I then execute

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PRIMARYKEY NOT IN ( " + myList.ToCSVString() + ")"
```

The reason I do this is because records are being added to the table via another process.

This query takes a long time to run and I also believe its throwing an OutOfMemoryException

Is there a better way to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server or your .NET app throwing OutOfMemory?

Comment: Looks like your in clause is around 20MB of string data.  You may want to add a timestamp to your table and get new records based on the created time.

Comment: The `OutOfMemoryException` is probably due to `myList.ToCSVString()`.  That would end up being a VERY long string with 200k items (probably 7*200k bytes or so).  Even if that worked, the SQL query would then be VERY slow.

Comment: Could you explain why there would be a OutOfMemoryException, surely 8 bytes * 200K is 1.5 megabytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server has a solution for this, add a [timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28SQL.90%29.aspx) column, every time you touch any row in the table the timestamp will grow.

Add an index for the timestamp column.

Instead of just storing ids in memory, store ids and last timestamp.

To update:

- select max timestamp
- select all the rows between old max timestamp and current max timestamp
- merge that into the list

Handling deletions is a bit more tricky, but can be achieved if you tombstone as opposed to delete.

Comment: +1 this is what we do for all of our tables in MySQL and we're running tables with millions of records.  Coming from an MSSQL background, I haven't fully given myself over to this method but at my current company it does work quite well (ie.fast)

Comment: So in C# store the Max TimeStamp in a variable every 5 mins then do a SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TimeStampe BETWEEN (myTimeStampVariable, MAX(TimeStampColumn)

Comment: @Jon, there is a little detail here that cuts down on concurrency issues, you select the max first, store it in a temp var and range it with the previous max. That way if another tran inserts new stuff before the select your new max includes all the records that were selected

Comment: Are you suggesting I do the temp var in SQL?  How do I store it in a temp var before doing the between SQL statement all in one statement to reduce concurrency

Comment: @Jon store the temp var in code. Its not a requirement to do this in a proc.

Comment: Yup thats what I was checking in my previous question but got confused with your concurrency reply.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the table?
If so, you might want to add a new auto incremented column that will serve as the PK `TableId`.

On each `SELECT` save the max id and on the next select add where `TableId > maxId`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an INT PK, and use something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE MY_ID > " + myList.Last().Id;
```

If you can't change your PK, create another column with date as type , and with NOW() as the default value and use it to query for new items.

Answer (score 0):

Create another table in the database with a single column for for the primary key. When your application starts, insert the PKs into this table. Then you can detect added keys directly with a select rather than checking the count:

```
select PrimaryKey from Table where PrimaryKey not in (select PrimaryKey from OtherTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this CSV list is large, I would recommend loading your file into a temp table, put an index on it and do a left join where null

```
select tbl.*
from table tbl
left join #tmpTable tmp on tbl.primarykey = tmp.primarykey
where tmp.primary key is null
```

edit: a Primary Key should not be a varchar. It should almost always be a incremented int/bigint. This would've been a lot easier. select * from table where primarykey > @lastknownkey

Smack the DB programmer who designed this.. :p

This design would also cause index fragmentation because rows won't be inserted in a linear fashion.